# Авторизация php-mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Как в php при работе с mysql не вводить каждый раз для определенной операции/запроса имя пользователя и пароль на конкретном примере?

Comment: Использовать $_SESSION - класть в этот массив признак, что пользователь залогинен.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте супер-глобальный массив *$_SESSION*, подробнее вы можете найти [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.session.php)

Или же вы можете использовать файлы COOKIE, подробнее о файлах Куки и как их использовать, вы также можете найти информацию на [официальном источнике PHP.NET](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.cookies.php)